# Brace expansion does not work

Tags: bash

In Bash, I want to rename a file so that the prefix up to `-` is removed, but why does it not work with brace expansion?

```
$ ls
Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-Operating Systems

$ mv {Thomas\ Anderson,\ Michael\ Dahlin-,}Operating\ Systems
mv: target ‘Operating Systems’ is not a directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contain `,` which is special to brace expansion, so your brace expansion expanded to *3* strings, instead of two as you intend.

You can try:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {Thomas\ Anderson,\ Michael\ Dahlin-,}Operating\ Systems
Thomas AndersonOperating Systems
 Michael Dahlin-Operating Systems
Operating Systems
```

to see how brace expansion was expanded.

---

The quick fix is escaping the `,`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {Thomas\ Anderson\,\ Michael\ Dahlin-,}Operating\ Systems
Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-Operating Systems
Operating Systems
```

Comment: Thanks. Why in bash, when I type the beginning of the filename and let it auto-complete, `,` isn't escaped, while in brace expansion I have to escape it?

Comment: What characters are special in "filename generation"? Does the manual say that somewhere?

Comment: By "filename generation", do you mean "filename expansion" or "filename autocompletion"? I thought you meant the latter.  Do they both have the same special characters?

Comment: @cuonglm Why not use "simple quoting": `printf '%s\n' {"Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-",}"Operating Systems"` faster, easier to understand and less prone to making mistakes.

Comment: @cuonglm The focus should be in giving the best way to repeat a correct use in the future. Quoting is the best solution to learn.

Comment: @Tim Auto-completion is escaping the `,` here. `ls Th->TAB` expands to: `ls Thomas\ Anderson\,\ Michael\ Dahlin-Operating\ Systems` all quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way is to use `printf` and `set --`.

Just the short version:

```
$ set -- {"Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-",}"Operating Systems"
$ mv "$@"
$ ls
Operating Systems
```

---

Or the more detailed description:
The original is not what you want:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {Thomas\ Anderson,\ Michael\ Dahlin-,}Operating\ Systems
Thomas AndersonOperating Systems
 Michael Dahlin-Operating Systems
Operating Systems
```

When it becomes what you want (quoting is the easiest way):

```
$ printf '%s\n' {"Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-",}"Operating Systems"
Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-Operating Systems
Operating Systems
```

Just change the `printf` to `set --` and use `mv "$@"`

```
$ mkdir mydir
$ cd mydir
$ touch 'Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-Operating Systems'
$ ls
Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-Operating Systems
$ printf '%s\n' {"Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-",}"Operating Systems"
Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-
Operating Systems
$ set -- {"Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-",}"Operating Systems"
$ printf '%s\n' "$@"
Thomas Anderson, Michael Dahlin-
Operating Systems
$ mv "$@"
$ ls
Operating Systems
```